# Color of the text in input [ MobileApp, KendoUI ]

Tags: css, cordova, kendo-ui

In my android app I have css like that:

```
input[type=text]{ 
    border:1px solid #c7c7c7;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color: black;
    width:100%; 
    padding: 10px;
}
```

and everything works except of the font-color in the input - it's white and I can't see what I'm writing. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
input[type="text"]{ 
border:1px solid #c7c7c7;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
color: black !important;
width:100%; 
padding: 10px;
```

}